# Java Unsigned Applet - Passing VM-argument "java.security.policy" is ignored?

Tags: java, security, applet, unsigned, policy

Before anyone asks me *why* I am doing this, or suggests that I sign the applet, or deploy it via JWS under J2EE client permissions, it is for purely academic reasons and to satisfy my own curiosity.

I am trying to provide a VM argument (java.security.policy) to point to the policy file used to govern the applet in question as shown below, but it seems to be ignored, consistently throwing a security exception.  I can find nothing in Oracle's documentation that states that this is to be expected.  Can anyone shed some light on this for me?  Thanks

(result)

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "frustrated.txt" "write")
```

(html)

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <applet name ="Frustrated" 
                code="com.test.Main.class" 
                archive="Frustrated.jar" 
                width="100" 
                height="100"
        >
            <PARAM name="separate_jvm" value="true">
            <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djava.security.policy=C:\Frustrated.policy">
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

(java)

```
package com.test;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends Applet
{
    @Override
    public final void init()
    {
        try
        {
            new FileOutputStream("frustrated.txt");
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

(policy)

```
grant
{
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djava.security.policy=C:\Frustrated.policy">
```

If it were possible to establish a custom policy through an applet parameter, that would be a (severe) security bug.

As an aside.  Given this is for *"purely academic reasons"* I'll add one of my common advices re. applets and academia.

> Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Although this is what I thought and expected, Oracle's documentation on the matter is non-existent (or at least I couldn't seem to find it).  Hopefully anyone else that has searched for an answer stumbles upon this page before wasting 4 hours re-reading documentation like I did tonight.  As an aside to your aside, I think that most CS teachers should stop teaching -- period.  Instead, give the jobs to those who have current real world experience in the subject rather than book-smart theoretical professors.

Comment: *"give the jobs to those who have current real world experience in the subject rather than book-smart theoretical professors."*  There is a big difference between being an expert in a field and being able to teach that expertise to others.  Personally, I'd prefer a teacher that is a great teacher, but with limited experience of the field, than an expert who can't teach to save their life. Besides, those with 'real world experience' typically earn significantly more than what educational institutions are prepared or able to pay. ;)

Comment: ...Seems as though I cannot edit my previous comment, so I'll just make a new one.  Could you link me to an authoritative source where you found this information?

Comment: Nope I could not.  It might be inferred from a (vague) collection of other resources and past experience.  The JVM goes through a process of 'check the security certificates and prompt the user' for normal applets/JWS apps.  While the JRE might be configured to prompt the user if it sees that argument, the code would presumably be unsigned.  As things progress with Oracle, it is getting to the stage when even 'self signed' code will be rejected by the JRE at the default security settings.  Unsigned code?  Forget about it..  For the sake of Java being seen as secure, no way that will work.

Comment: One final comment on the matter...I find it very odd that the policy file is either seemingly accepted, or is simply unsandboxed when using the appletviewer tool bundled with the JDK.  That is what initially led me to believe that my initial expectation wasn't the case.